# error_complexity using std regex, how do I increase allowed complexity of search operation?

Tags: c++, regex

> error_complexity  The complexity of an attempted match against a
>   regular expression exceeded a pre-set level.

I get an regex_error thrown saying this. How can I fix?

Comment: Can you show your regex? Perhaps it can be optimized somehow.

Comment: im parsing a 1500 line document, and pulling several words that are separated in a 200 word span of the doc.

Comment: Then could you possibly remove some of the noise in between? or compress it somehow? Finding repeated words is not a task for regular expressions per-se, although regex engines support it.

Comment: no I can't really, I dont mind it taking extra time to compute, i just want the error to go away. Is there any way?

Comment: Not that I know of. perhaps recompiling the library. And even then, you don't really know if it will be enough, if your problem is exponential... see e.g. [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)

Comment: Could you post the regex? Are you using Boost or std::regex? What is the Compiler and its options?

Comment: I'm using std::regex. The regex is beside the point because I know it's minimal valid regex, and I've even tested it in another language but I need a c++ solution. I guess the std library is just bad? I'm using VS2015. Think boost would be better? I'll try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way, VC++ std::regex is very bad. Switched to boost, fixed problem.