# Issue with regular expressions in C++

Tags: c++, regex

I tried to use the following regular expression, which already works in `C#`, in `C++` as well but it's not working in `C++`.

```
std::regex r = std::regex("([^%]*(%[.[0-9]*]?[a-z])*)*", std::regex::extended);
```

it manages to match several strings and reject others correctly, but gets stuck (really stuck - no error) on the string "%d smaller than available pbn % f %d", which it should reject (since there is a % that's not immediately preceded by a legal suffix).

Using `std::regex r = std::regex("(([^%]*)(%(\\.([0-9]*))?[a-z])*)*");` exhibits exactly the same behavior i described before. (i assume those two regexes are equivalent - just one is in canonical form like C# uses and the second is ECMAScript like the c++ default)

I am not sure what's the problem. 
Also i want to match the entire string to that pattern so it matches only if the entire string matches as a whole. So i want to use `regex_match` for that purpose. I use the following code in C++:

```
if (std::regex_match(str, r))
```

Also, in C# i use the following code to perform that check (that the entire string matches as a whole):

```
        Regex^ r = gcnew Regex("([^%]*(%[.[0-9]*]?[a-z])*)*", RegexOptions::IgnoreCase);
        Match^ m = r->Match(str);
        if (m->Success && m->Groups[0]->Length== str->Length)
```

Just to give an example of what i want the regular expression to match is:

Got event `%s` (`%d`) in state `%s` (`%d`), moving to state `%s` (`%d`) ...

or

Some `%.34x` event

And the regular expression is supposed not to match the following:

Some `%` stuff.

To explain in words what the regex should do - it should accept the only string that all the occurrences (if any) of % in them is immediately preceded by a letter or by a .46456x (aka . some numbers and a letter) and reject all others.

UPDATE:
The regex that works is `^([^%]|%((\\.)?[0-9]+)?[a-zA-Z])*$` . The problem is that unlike the C# regex this one is really slow and slows down the application by ALOTTT. So i was thinking maybe it's better to maybe use std::regex_search in order to find if there is an occurrence of % that's not immediately followed either by a latter or by a .NUMBERS and then a letter or by NUMBERS and then a letter. Will appreciate help with a regex that does that.

Update 2:

I am using the regex `^.*%(?!([.]?[0-9]+)?[a-zA-Z]).*$` which works, and i use it with std::regex_search. It's much faster then the previous solution but still much slower then the C# version (43 seconds vs less then 6 seconds in C#). Is there a way to optimize it even farther?

Comment: Anyway, lots of backtracking problem potential exists.

Comment: Please show the exact error message. `std::regex_error` (like most exceptions) contains a message stating exactly what the problem is

Comment: The full error is: "regex_error(error_brack): The expression contained mismatched [ and ]." And i was trying to write in the part [.[0-9]*]? - that the entire part of .[0-9]* is optional. So i guess \\. but i am not sure what's ?:

Comment: This is how engines parse that regex part `(` `%` `[.[0-9]*` `]?` `[a-z]` `)*` which is not an error. See if you can spot the problems.

Comment: @sln I am using C++ which means the default is ECMAScript. And this exact regex is working both in C# and on websites for regex checking. I don't know what the error is in C++ and i need some help with that.

Comment: "...that the entire part of .[0-9]* is optional" This doesn't make sense.  In a context where nothing needs quoted, `[.[0-9]` would be a character class matching either a `.`, or a `[`, or a digit from `0` to `9`; `*` would mean that atom can be repeated 0 or more times; `]` would be a literal end square brace, and `?` would only apply to `]`.  `?` cannot apply to `[.[0-9]*]` because that's not an atom in your expression.  I don't know if you intend to match `[` and `]` optionally or not, but this expression is almost certainly not what you intend.

Comment: @HWalters i have updates my post with the recent regex i am using the with examples of what i want it and don't want it to match

Comment: If you just care about the construct error, you can use a catch, where the `e` exception has a nice code and a pointer to an error string. This would be for a mfc app: `try { .. } catch ( std::regex_error & e ) { int code = e.code(); std::string str( e.what ); MessageBox( CString( str ) ); }` But, I doubt it is a regex_error via construction.

Comment: It is a regex_error as i have mentioned it, and the code is 5

Comment: Also, i have read that C# uses a canonical regular expression by default while C++ uses only ECMAScript, so i guess it makes sense that translation is needed. I will appreciate some help doing that

Comment: visual studio 2015

Comment: I wrote the exact error in my original post (after updating the regex the new error is) - "The expression contained mismatched ( and )."  Before updating it to use () instead of [] the error was "The expression contained mismatched [ and ]."

Comment: Well your last regex is no mystery; exactly as stated, you have mismatched `(` and `)` (you have 6 `(`'s and 5 `)`'s).

Comment: The fixed one is `(([^%]*)(%(\\.[0-9]*)?[a-z])*)*` but I cannot make out what it must match, surely it does not match what you want. Moreover, I doubt you really want to repeat a capturing group as you won't be able to access all the captures, as in C#.

Comment: It may help, rather than listing examples, to explain in words what you're _intending_ to try to match (something like, "matches every string, given that every `%` is followed by a-z, with an optional number with one (or more?) optional `.`'s in it between the two)?".  Best I have is a fuzzy gut feeling you want all of the `%` sequences to look something like printf specifiers.

Comment: @HWalters thanks!!!. I have changed it to (([^%]*)(%(\\.([0-9]*))?[a-z])*)* and it almost works. It works on many inputs but gets stuck on this one (and i mean stuck) - "Got ASSERT !!! (Condition: reportFullPbn >= reportAvailablePbn) Hub reported full pbn (%d) smaller than available pbn (%)"

Comment: @sln this is not the siolution (sending 0) - it just reject everything now.

Comment: @HWalters i want a regex that will accept only strings that all of the appearances of % (if any) are immediately followed either by a letter or by a .436456x (aka - followed by a dot, and then a sequence of numbers and then a letter). I want to verify that it's a correct format string for a function - aka all the % are followed by a type specifier. And  Wiktor Stribiżew, i don't want to access any of the capture groups - i just want to know whether a string matches fully to this regex - aka there isn't a sing;e % that's not followed by the described above suffix

Comment: @sln it's not about the flags. And when i set the flag to 0 it just rejects all inputs. So it's wrong anyway

Comment: @sln it doesn't throw after fixing it to the following pattern either  (([^%]*)(%(\\.[0-9]*)?[a-z])*)* - and doesn't reject everything as a bonus :) But there is a problem with that pattern as i have mentioned in a previous comment. It gets weirdly stuck when using it on the input "Got ASSERT !!! (Condition: reportFullPbn >= reportAvailablePbn) Hub reported full pbn (%d) smaller than available pbn (%)"

Comment: @sln sorry what?

Comment: Please edit your requirements and additional information into the question instead of commenting it. Comments might be deleted any time, then noone knows what you want anymore.

Comment: Please give a **sample input string** and a **sample desire output** the `C#` regex engine is different from `C++` one

Comment: @sln it's not working correctly - for example it doesn't match "%d smaller than available pbn %d" which is a legal string. Also, when setting the flag of the reget to std::regex::extended i can use my original regex from C# - "([^%]*(%[.[0-9]*]?[a-z])*)*". it's still gets unexplainably stuck with the string "%d smaller than available pbn % f %d" just like the regex (([^%]*)(%(\\.([0-9]*))?[a-z])*)* when using std::regex::ECMAScript. So the question is why, I am not sure why it works in C# and not here.

Comment: @grek40 just updated the ost with all the latest info

Comment: @k-five there are examples in the post

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to add relevant information to the question. Comments are not a good place for that.

Comment: @n.m as i have said to grek40  a few minutes ago i have just updated the original post with all the info :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error_complexity using std regex, how do I increase allowed complexity of search operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33817576/error-complexity-using-std-regex-how-do-i-increase-allowed-complexity-of-search) (see also [this](http://rextester.com/ITYA71758))

Comment: @sln it's not working correctly. It can't even match "%d dfs d" which is correct. Jut to be clear - i want a regex that will accept (aka match the entire string, that's why i am using std::regex_match) EVERY string that all of the occurrences of % in the string (if any - there may not be any % in the string and it's okay) are immediately followed either by a letter that'd adjacent to them or by a . and several numbers and then a letter (e.g "dst %d sdsd %.4545x dfsdf")

Comment: @n.m. i can't use external library. So boost isn't an option. All i want is to be able to detect strings that comply with the requirement  that all of the occurrences of % in the string (if any - there may not be any % in the string and it's okay) are immediately followed either by a letter that'd adjacent to them or by a . and several numbers and then a letter (e.g "dst %d sdsd %.4545x dfsdf"). If regex in C++ are too primitive what's another way to do this in an efficient way?

Comment: "i can't use external library." What kind of requirement is that? If you need to do the job, use a tool that works. If you need to satisfy your higher-ups, I don't know what you should do, sorry. If you want to ask another question, [ask a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Your edit - the regex `^.*%(?!([.]?[0-9]+)?[a-zA-Z]).*$` - is that **really** working? It doesn't match anything said earlier. It will match `%%%%%%%` for example... And it'll only check one formatting. Your example `Got event %s (%d) in state %s (%d), moving to state %s (%d)` has four of them.

Comment: I've had a felling all along that your after matching a C `printf` format string - is that anywhere near the truth?

Comment: @ClasG yes i want to make sure it's a correct format string. I believe i have mentioned it somewhere.

Comment: I voted to close this post. It seems you do not know what you want, and are unclear in your problem statement. It changes by the hour... You're way over your head with regular expressions and I would suggest you learn the basics before trying to apply it, or at least understand them while you do.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go, all `%` in string must be compliant.
If so, match the entire string, if not, don't match
the string.

I suggest you do this with i.e. `if ( regex_search( sTarget, sRx, sMatch, flags ) )`
but *regex_match()* would do the same thing.

[^(?:[^%]*%(?:\.[0-9]*)?[a-z])+[^%]*$](https://regex101.com/r/azgpxy/6)

Expanded

```
 ^                             # BOS
 (?:                           # Cluster begin
      [^%]*                         # Not % characters
      %                             # % found
      (?: \. [0-9]* )?              # optional .###
      [a-z]                         # single a-z required
 )+                            # Cluster end, 1 to many times
 [^%]*                         # Not % characters
 $                             # EOS
```

Comment: @n.m - Did you try to run this regex ? [^(?:\[^%\]*%(?:\.\[0-9\]*)?\[a-z\])+\[^%\]*$](https://regex101.com/r/azgpxy/6) What's the problem ?

Comment: @n.m. - I don't know what you're talking about, doesn't throw any error: http://rextester.com/XKO93751

Comment: I _think_ the intent was for strings without any `%`'s in them to match; this expression mismatches such strings.

Comment: Two of his comments seem to suggest that strings without `%`'s are accepted ("accept only strings that all of the appearances of % (if any) are"; "if any" here suggests qualifying "only", such that strings with no %'s match vacuously).  In the other comment: "there may not be any % in the string and it's okay", I take "it's okay" to _also_ imply this is a match in the same situation.  darkThoughts can clarify, but I don't see a reading where he intends such strings to not match.  (If you do, for now I would just defer to dT to clarify).

Comment: @HWalters - It looks like he wants to qualify every `%` found, that it is valid. The other stuff about matching the string if it's got no % in it, just change one quantifier: `^(?:[^%]*%(?:\.[0-9]*)?[a-z])*[^%]*$` but that also matches the empty string, which is ok. He just wants to validate the %'s in the string. So, the entire thing is a pass/fail based on match, but that won't tell you if there are any %'s in the string.

Answer (score 1):

A simple regular expression that works with VC++ and fits your description would be

```
  std::regex("^([^%]|%(\\.[0-9]+)?[a-zA-Z])*$", std::regex::extended)
```

[Live demo](http://rextester.com/NEDV50342)

(Change `[0-9]+` to `[0-9]*` if digits after `%.` should be optional).

Comment: You don't have to force it to POSIX. By default, ECMAScript is selected so just leave it blank. On a regex note, the alternation in your regex slows it down. `Regex1:   ^([^%]|%(\.[0-9]+)?[a-zA-Z])*$
    Options:  < none >    Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
    Matches found per iteration:   1    Elapsed Time:    1.16 s,   1159.80 ms,   1159795 µs Regex2:   ^(?:[^%]*%(?:\.[0-9]*)?[a-z])+[^%]*$
    Options:  < none >    Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
    Matches found per iteration:   1    Elapsed Time:    0.46 s,   455.71 ms,   455707 µs`

Comment: Here they are with the ECMAScript flag http://rextester.com/ZLRRI60186
http://rextester.com/BBYGH36301

Comment: I would guess this is because of capturing/non-capturing groups, not because of alterations @sln

Comment: @ClasG please feel free to expand on your claim and/or downvote.

Comment: Yeah, the capture groups take some overhead. Identical except alternation. `Regex1:   ^(?:[^%]|%(?:\.[0-9]+)?[a-zA-Z])*$
    Options:  < none >
    Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
    Matches found per iteration:   1
    Elapsed Time:    0.66 s,   659.61 ms,   659605 µs
    
    
    Regex2:   ^(?:[^%]*%(?:\.[0-9]+)?[a-zA-Z])+[^%]*$
    Options:  < none >
    Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
    Matches found per iteration:   1
    Elapsed Time:    0.46 s,   460.27 ms,   460273 µs`

Comment: Well, as I explained in my answer, I **assume** OP has made an error saying that the percent should be "immediately preceded by a letter". I guess (as did you and @sln judging from your regex'es) that it should be "followed" by it. But since you have a `+` after digits, it **requires** digits, which I believe is faulty. (Easily fixed though ;)

Comment: @ClasG - "immediately preceded by a letter" - that's `followed` not preceded. And, my regex is _optional_ `[0-9]*` not a `+`

Comment: @ClasG  That's how I interpret "some numbers and a letter" but of course OP might need something else entirely. Answer edited.

Comment: @sln Huh... Yeah... That's what I'm saying. OP says preceded, I believe he/she means followed. And that was directed to n.m.

Comment: @n.m. Well... Reading the regex supplied in the question suggests `*`, not `+` ;)

Comment: @n.m. thanks - your regex worked, i just changed it a bit to ^([^%]|%((\\.)?[0-9]+)?[a-zA-Z])*$ but it works. The problem is that unlike the C# regex this one is really slow and slows down the application by ALOTTT. So i was thinking maybe it's better to maybe use a regex_search in order to find if there is an occurrence of % that's not immediately followed either by a latter or by a .NUMBERS and then a letter or by NUMBERS and then a letter. Will appreciate help with a regex that does that.

Comment: If you need maximum speed write a custom parser. In my simple test a custom parser is about 60 times faster than a regex-based checker.

Comment: @n.m what do you mean by custom parser? Actually going over the string char by char and making sure the requirements are met? And you really think it will be faster then using the built in regex?

Comment: Yes I really do, because I have tested and timed it.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar sln's, but it's shorter and doesn't require a `%` part to match:

```
^(?:[^%]*(?:%\.?[0-9]*[a-z])?)*$
```

First - everything between `^` (start of line) and `$` (end of line) is optional, so an empty string is accepted.

In an optional, non capturing group `(?:...)`, match any number of anything but a `%`. Then, optionally, match a `%`, optionally followed by a `.`, and then any number of digits and finally a letter. Repeat this for any number of times.

(I, as the others answering, and as the regex provided in the question suggests, assume that OP doesn't mean "immediately preceded by a letter", but instead followed by one, right?)

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/RoDOS2/1).

Comment: Unfortunately it's too short. It matches `%999` when it shouldn't.